# Class cast exception with MSSQL drivers

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, wildfly

I am trying to modify an existing legacy application by porting few queries and making them compatible with MSSQL server. Some part is already written and I am actually integrating TVP with Java code.

But when I try to execute my code I get a weird exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement cannot be cast
>   to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement

This is the code I have written. `MY_NUMBER` is actually a Table type.

```
CallableStatement stmt = ((WrappedCallableStatementJDK7) cstmt).getUnderlyingStatement();
        SQLServerDataTable tbl = new SQLServerDataTable();
        tbl.addColumnMetadata("key", Types.INTEGER);
        tbl.addColumnMetadata("value", Types.INTEGER);
        tbl.addRow(0, 0);
        SQLServerCallableStatement statement = (SQLServerCallableStatement) stmt;
        statement.setStructured(thisPSParamObj.getParameterName(), "DBO.MY_NUMBER", tbl);
```

Comment: I am suspecting it is a classpath issue. If somebody could point me towards setting right classpath in wildfly, It would be really great!

Comment: Check if you have two different versions of driver jars (one in the modules and one in the application).